# How to install Tweepy with Anacondas and easy_install

Tags: tweepy, anaconda

I am having problems installing Tweepy in Anacondas Python 3.3.

First of all I went to the scripts directory of my Python 3.3 installation.  Then I ran

```
easy_install tweepy
```

If I run it in my default Python Scripts directory it works, but that is an old Python version that I do not want to use.

My output is below.  It says something about importing quotes.

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts>easy_install tweepy
Searching for tweepy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/tweepy/
Best match: tweepy 2.3.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/t/tweepy/tweepy-2.3.0.tar.gz#md5=065c80d244360988c61d64b5dfb7e229
Processing tweepy-2.3.0.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-tmda2q\tweepy-2.3.0\setup.cfg
Running tweepy-2.3.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-tmda2q\tweepy-2.3.0\egg-dist-tmp-006ghp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1986, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1967, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1990, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 930, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 949, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 360, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 604, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 634, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 829, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1109, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1095, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 34, in run_setup
    lambda: exec(compile(open(
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 82, in run
    return func()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'})
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-tmda2q\tweepy-2.3.0\tweepy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-tmda2q\tweepy-2.3.0\tweepy\models.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-tmda2q\tweepy-2.3.0\tweepy\utils.py", line 9, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name quote
```

Comment: Are you sure tweepy supports Python 3? This looks like an implicit relative import, which no longer work in Python 3.

Comment: Also, you should prefer pip over easy_install.

Comment: it can be implemented by pip easily, run "pip install tweepy" is fine.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using Anaconda for python.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy

Install tweepy from terminal like this:

`conda install -c conda-forge tweepy`

`-c` denotes channel = `conda-forge`

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/199, tweepy doesn't support Python 3. So you'll need to use Python 2. Since you are using Anaconda, you can create a conda environment for Python 2

```
conda create -n py2 python=2 anaconda
activate  py2
pip install tweepy
```

Alternately, you could try a different Twitter library for Python, such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for 2017.
According to the [tweepy github](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)

> The easiest way to install the latest version is by using pip/easy_install to pull it from PyPI:
>
> `pip install tweepy`
>
> You may also use Git to clone the repository from Github and install it manually:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git  
> cd tweepy  
> python setup.py install
> ```
>
> Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 & 3.5 are supported.

While this is not an answer specific to conda, the [documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages) says that if a project cannot be found on their site then it is recommended to use another installer such as pip. And indeed, the Anaconda.org page on [tweepy](https://anaconda.org/pypi/tweepy) lists pip as the installer.
Python 3+ should come with pip. Otherwise you can clone/install.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can install tweepy using conda as follows:

`conda install -c hargup/label/pypi tweepy`

[Reference anaconda docs](https://anaconda.org/hargup/tweepy)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

#### python3.[version] -m pip install [package-name]

-in your case use this

python3.3 -m pip install tweepy

Answer (score 0):

Install tweepy from terminal like this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```